# How does the modified Newton's method for multiple roots converge quadratically?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I am currently learning about the multiple root issue for Newton's method. My textbook hinted at tweaking the function using
$$h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f′(x)}$$
and making the iteration function to actually be
$$g(x)= x - \frac{h(x)}{h'(x)}$$

My textbook claims that this method is also quadratically convergent but provided no proof and I am lost as to how it is quadratically convergent. I tried to do some more research but all I could find is this: https://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/sryedida/public_html/caimna/transcendental/iteration%20methods/accelerating%20the%20convergence/mrac.html

Can anybody show me how this quadratically convergent or at least point me in the direction to prove it myself?

Comment: If $r$ is the root of $f$, then $r$ is a root of $h$ with multiplicity $1$. Alternative: It should be possible to show that $g'(r) = 0$. This will also be enough, depending on what theorems you already have.

Comment: I understand how if *r* is a root of *f* then *r* is a root of *h* with multiplicity 1 but I am failing to understand how that implies quadratic convergence. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Local quadratic convergence is ensured when the the function is sufficiently smooth and the root has multiplicity $1$.

Comment: There are some related posts on this [here]( https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bnumerical-methods%5D+modified+newton). It is likely that they can help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** That method is known as [Schröder's Method](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchroedersMethod.html) and the iteration formula may be obtained by applying Newton's method to $f(x)/f'(x)$ instead of $f(x)$.